# Python - how to delete all characters in all lines after some sign?

Tags: python, regex

I want to delete all characters in all lines after the `@` sign.
I wrote some piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, urllib2
url = 'http://varenhor.st/wp-content/uploads/emails.txt'
document = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = document.read()

html2 = html[0]
for x in html.rsplit('@'):
    print x
```

But it only deletes `@` sign and copies the rest of characters into next line.
So how I can modify this code, to delete all characters in all lines after `@`?
Should I use a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting too many times; use [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) instead and just ignore the part after `@`. Do this *per line*:

```
for line in html.splitlines():
    cleaned = line.rpartition('@')[0]
    print cleaned
```

or, for older Python versions, limit `str.rsplit()` to just 1 split, and again only take the first result:

```
for line in html.splitlines():
    cleaned = line.rsplit('@', 1)[0]
    print cleaned
```

I used [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to cleanly split a text regardless of newline style. You can also loop directly over the `urllib2` response file object:

```
url = 'http://varenhor.st/wp-content/uploads/emails.txt'
document = urllib2.urlopen(url)
for line in document:
    cleaned = line.rpartition('@')[0]
    print cleaned
```

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'http://varenhor.st/wp-content/uploads/emails.txt'
>>> document = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> for line in document:
...     cleaned = line.rpartition('@')[0]
...     print cleaned
... 
ADAKorb...
AllisonSarahMoo...
Artemislinked...
BTBottg...
BennettLee...
Billa...
# etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's slice notation:

```
import re
import sys
import urllib2

url = 'http://varenhor.st/wp-content/uploads/emails.txt'
document = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = document.read()

for line in html.splitlines():
    at_index = line.index('@')
    print line[:at_index]
```

Since strings are sequences, you can slice them. For instance,

```
hello_world = 'Hello World'
hello = hello_world[:5]
world = hello_world[6:]
```

Bear in mind, slicing returns a new sequence and doesn't modify the original sequence.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when I run this code, I see error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 11, in <module>
    at_index = line.index('@')
ValueError: substring not found

Comment: Do you run it on the provided url (`http://varenhor.st/wp-content/uploads/emails.txt`)? I manage to run it ok; that error indicates that one of the lines doesn't have an '@' character

Comment: At any rate, @Martijn's solutions is nicer (though it's not more efficient; which isn't an issue in this case):-) But I am interested to know why you couldn't make this to work!

Comment: Edit, I am sorry s16h, your solution works of course, I entered it manually, but when I paste it, it works good.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already `import`ed `re`, you can use it:

```
document = urllib2.urlopen(url)
reg_ptn = re.compile(r'@.*')
for line in document:
    print reg_ptn.sub('', line)
```

Comment: Regular expressions are very slow; but it's still good to see how this can be solved in different ways.

Comment: Test if before you make claims.

Comment: Regular expressions are known to be slow; but anyhow, your code: 11143 function calls (11046 primitive calls) in 1.044 seconds. Matrijn's code: 6248 function calls (6152 primitive calls) in 0.459 seconds. My code, 6253 function calls (6157 primitive calls) in 0.471 seconds.